# TensorFlow and preparing data for MS COCO

Tags: python, json, tensorflow

I can't quite figure out how to prepare the data to use with the MS COCO dataset. I'm currently saving all of the data in `TFRecord`s. For each record, I need to save the jpeg data as well as all of the annotations. For each image, there can be up to ~20 annotations and for each of those annotations, there can be multiple polygons in a python list.

For example, I iterate over all the segmentations and later on save it in a `TFRecord`.

```
obj = { 'annotation/' + str(imgNb) + '/seg/' + str(_key): _float_feature(segmentations[_key]) for _key in range(len(segmentations))}
```

The problem in doing this is that I end up with variable length `TFRecord`s. When I want to call `parse_single_example`, I need to send a feature_map, but I don't know the exact number of annotations. The `feature_map` would need to be pretty big, assuming a worst-case scenario.

I also tried saving it with JSON files, but I still need to use `parse_single_example` to parse the JSON and so I still have the initial problem.

So the question: 
Should I create a really big `feature_map` and at every training step I check which ones are empty, or should I try to process the annotations' data before saving it in `TFRecord`s (transform it into images, this would make for some pretty big files, but could be doable I guess)? Or is there a better way?

Any help or insight is appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off either (1) putting all annotations as the same feature or (2) always putting all features in all examples, but leaving empty values for the absent ones.